# Select element not accepting clicks when ng-click is in parent element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

Quick question really. I've noticed that when I have an ng-click above a select element, clicking on the select list does not change the value.

html:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController" ng-app>
  <div ng-click="test()">
    <select size="1" ng-model="selectedCountry" ng-options="c.name for c in countries"></select>
    {{selectedCountry}}
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ky5F4/131/

Could anyone care to explain why this is happening and if there is a way to prevent this? I would like to have a click event on the parent firing as well as the select ng-model bound data changing. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you add `ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()"` to your select.

> The event.stopPropagation() method stops the bubbling of an event to parent elements, preventing any parent event handlers from being executed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-controller="MyController" ng-app>

    <select size="1" ng-model="selectedCountry" ng-options="c.name for c in countries" ng-change="changed()"></select>
    {{selectedCountry}}

</div>
```

**Controller**

```
 $scope.changed = function()
    {

        if($scope.modelname == "Whatever Your Parent Element is")
    {
        //whatever you want to do
    }
    }
```